# Storing case object with squeryl

Tags: scala, squeryl

How do I store user case objects with squeryl? I have an Account object with a permission field of type Permission (defined as a sealed trait). I also have 2 case objects (Administrator and NormalUser) extending from Permission. How can I persist the Account class using Squeryl. Example code below:

```
sealed trait Permission
case object Administrator extends Permission
case object NormalUser extends Permission

case class Account(
        id: Long, 
        email: String,
        permission: Permission
) extends KeyedEntity[Long]
```

Comment: The answer to this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167431/relations-and-foreign-keys-in-squeryl It shows how to have two objects reference each other using a ManyToOne relation.

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping. I have no problems creating relations in squeryl. Do you mean that I have to save Permission to its own table and then create a relation to Account? It has to be another way, just as for enums (I could use enums, but they do not work as good with pattern matching).

Comment: Also, if you don't get a definitive explanation here, you may want to post a message to the squeryl mailing list (squeryl@googlegroups.com). They are pretty good about helping out there.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed it was a persistent class. You may want to look at the custom types section here: http://squeryl.org/schema-definition.html. That may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, if you use a custom type to retrieve the permission type, such that it persists to the database as an integer (in the example below 1 and 0), you can override the unapply method to lookup the case object and pattern matching should work fine. I imagine something like the following should work:

```
class Permission(identifier:Int) extends org.squeryl.customtypes.IntField(identifier) {
  self: CustomType[Int] =>

  private lazy val permissions = 
    List(Administrator, NormalUser).
      map(p => p.value -> p).
      toMap

  def unapply = permissions.get(value)
}

case object Administrator extends Permission(1)
case object NormalUser extends Permission(0)
```

Then you should be able to store the permission directly in your code, using your entity definition:

```
case class Account(
        id: Long, 
        email: String,
        permission: Permission
) extends KeyedEntity[Long]
```

you can set the `permission` field directly as `Administrator` or `NormalUser` and you should also be able to pattern match like:

```
account.permission match {
  case Administrator => ..
  case NormalUser => ..
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that because class Permission isn't sealed, it can not properly verify exhaustiveness on pattern matches.  If it was sealed, because it isn't abstract, then a warning will be issued that exhaustiveness is not reached, saying that it would fail on the following input: Permission().  

To make correct case object enums, the super type (in this case permission) must be sealed and abstract, but if the class is abstract, squeryl will fail when trying to instantiate the class from the database value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define schema:

```
 object Library extends Schema {

     val authors = table[Author]("AUTHORS")
 }
```

and then insert entity:

```
 authors.insert(new Author("Herby Hancock"))
```

http://squeryl.org/schema-definition.html

http://squeryl.org/inserts-updates-delete.html

In order to store Permission  it must inherit one of the subtypes of CustomType in the package
org.squeryl.customtypes, and import the org.squeryl.customtypes.CustomTypesMode._
into the scope where statements are defined. For details read section Custom Types here: http://squeryl.org/schema-definition.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm still not sure how to make Permission storable. Neither traits or class objects take parameters. Could you provide a simple example for storing case object fields?