# How to store Scala's ADT using Squeryl?

Tags: mysql, database, scala, squeryl

I have this code:

```
sealed abstract class VehicleType

case object Bus         extends VehicleType
case object Trolleybus  extends VehicleType
case object Tram        extends VehicleType
case object Metro       extends VehicleType

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

case class Vehicle(id: Int,    
               cityId: Int,
               vehicleType: VehicleType,
               vehicleName: String,
               vehicleCost: Float) extends KeyedEntity[Int] {

  lazy val city: ManyToOne[City] = ACrossSchema.vehicleToCity.right(this)

}
```

How to save "vehicleType" in MySQL database using Squeryl?

Comment: Perhaps an approach like this would work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219104/storing-case-object-with-squeryl

Comment: it's bad solution. I try to do the same, but after mapping from DB to scala class, it cant evolute to class. I just create enum and save id in db.